# Issues with asynchronous nature of redux in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm pulling data into one of my parent components and then using various filter statements which are based on user choices from select boxes. I'm then calling an action which simply stores that filtered data based on the users search into global state so that my child components can access them.

One of my child components is supposed to render the results but what is happening is the results being rendered are lagging one action behind. I've encountered similar issues when using set state and my solution then was to use a callback but I'm not exactly sure how to go about dealing with this issue in this situation with redux.

The wordpress.get is just named import of axios config.

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
    const response = await wordpress.get(
      "*********************/api/wp/v2/variants?per_page=100"
    );
    this.props.fetchData(response);
    const data = []
    response.data.forEach(ele => {
        data.push(ele)
    })
    this.props.sendFilteredView(data);
};
handleChange = () => {
    this.preBuiltFiltering();
};
```

I've left out pre-built filtering because its long and excessive, all it does is run the filter based on the users choices and then dispatches the this.props.sendFilteredView action with the filtered data set as the argument. The action just returns the payload.

I then am rendering the results of the filter in a child component by accessing the global state (I also tried just passing it directly through props, same issue).

Comment: The fact that you get the same issue with just passing props should be telling that the problem isn't redux.

Comment: I was passing the store data as props into the child, sorry for not being clear

Comment: You will need to add a lot more code for any help. What is `fetchData`? What does `sendFilteredView` look like? If they simply set some redux state, then there shouldnt be any problem. My guess is the issue is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It’s an async function, you’re using a callback after the forEach with data.

So you need to wait forEach been completed.

Try to use await before forEach.

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
    const response = await wordpress.get(
      "*********************/api/wp/v2/variants?per_page=100"
);
    this.props.fetchData(response);
    const data = []
    await response.data.forEach(ele => {
        data.push(ele)
    })
    this.props.sendFilteredView(data);
};
handleChange = () => {
    this.preBuiltFiltering();
  };
```

Comment: Care to explain the need to add `await` keyword?

Comment: It’s an async function, he is calling a callback after the forEach with data. So he need to wait the forEach been completed.